# Xcode creates a duplicate of my project's root folder with build info, how to disable that

Tags: xcode8

I'm quite new in iOS development and I'm observing that next to the root folder of my project (let's say its name is 'Foo') another folder is created with a cryptic name (like 'Foo-gobovuchatrabdsdfg...'). In it some information about builds and simulator debugging is stored.

How can stop Xcode creating that folders or if not possible, how can I specify a different path for that folder?

Answer (score 0):

The folder with a cryptic name is your derived data folder, which contains the files Xcode creates when it builds your project. If you don't want the derived data folder inside your project folder, change the derived date folder location to the default location. Refer to the following question to learn how to change the derived data location:

[Xcode DerivedData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953545/xcode-deriveddata-folder)